# McLaurin expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}.$

Tags: calculus

A sub-problem of my problem is to show that $|R_2(x)|\leq 5\cdot 10^{-3}$ if $0\leq x \leq 0.1.$ This is what I need help with.

In the first sub-problems I'm asked to find the first order McLaurin polynomial, $p_1(x)$ of the function $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x}.$ This is easy:

$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2{\sqrt{1+x}}} \Rightarrow p_1(x)=1+\frac{x}{2}.$

The rest-term on Lagrange's form is $R_2(x)=-\frac{1}{8(1+\theta x)^{3/2}}x^2,$ where $\theta \in [0,1].$ So the question is, how do I show that the error is less than or equal to $5\cdot10^{-3}$, for $x\in[0,0.1]?$

Comment: Using that $0\le x\le 0.1$ $$\left|\frac{1}{8(1+\theta x)^{3/2}}x^2\right|\le \left|\frac{1}{8(1+\theta\cdot 0)^{3/2}}\cdot 0.1^2\right|\le \frac{1}{500}$$

Answer (score 0):

The function :

$$R_2(x)=-\frac{1}{8(1+\theta x)^{3/2}}x^2$$

is increasing for $\theta \in [0,1] \space \text{and} \space x \in [0,0.1]$.

One can easily see that :

$$\left|\frac{1}{8(1+\theta x)^{3/2}}x^2\right|\le \left|\frac{1}{8(1+\ 1\cdot 0.1)^{3/2}}\cdot 0.1^2\right|\le \frac{1}{500}$$

Comment: Ah okay, but shouldn't you choose $x=0$ and $\theta=0$, since $R_2(x)$ is maximum for those two values?